# Function to automate the password field with different character each time

Tags: java, selenium, mobile

I need to write the java Selenium code for the login function of a website.
The user is prompted to enter three different characters from their password for example 3rd, 6th and 8th characters, each in separate text fields; the characters requested will change each time the user attempts to login, as a result I'm struggling to automate. In my test environment the password is always set to Password1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Can you please state the problem you're having as a clear, concise question?  And could you please add some code to your post that shows what you've already tried?

Comment: if ( driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@content-desc=\"1st character of password\"]")).isEnabled() )
    {
     Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("com.barclays.absa.banking.uat:id/et_password1")).sendKeys("p");   

    }
    
    else if (driver.findElement(By.id("com.barclays.absa.banking.uat:id/et_password2")).isEnabled())
    {
  Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("com.barclays.absa.banking.uat:id/et_password2")).sendKeys("a");   
    }

Comment: You need to give more context than that.  Can you edit your original post to include more code, as well as pictures?  Also, what problem are you having, exactly?